# Will my package run successfully by using SQL Server Agent if I have data viewers enabled and breakpoint

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

Will my package run successfully by using SQL Server Agent if I have data viewers enabled and breakpoint? I'm using SQL Server 2008 - SSIS.

Comment: Please provide more infomation

Comment: pls..do provide more info about the package you're working on,and what you are trying to do on it.!!

Answer (score 2):

Breakpoints and Data Viewers are only artifacts that have meaning within the debugger. If running your package from SQL Agent fails, then there's a whole host of things that could be wrong, generally permission related, but a data viewer or a breakpoint will not be one of them.

Comment: Downvoter, can you provide some context as to the DV?

Answer (score 0):

No. Breakpoints and data viewers will not be a hinderance. Your package should run successfully if there are no other errors.

Answer (score 0):

In This Scenario ,Answer is NO.
When create a breakpoints then we have to press next of F5 for proceed the package .
In case of data viewer there is prompt for check OK so ultimately job get failed .